# login regestarion password and confirmpassword verification & validation in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite

I am new to iPhone programing. I am developing an application. My requirement is

In my first view I will enter the password and confirm password insert into sqlite. Then validation will be perform. After then if password will be match then then next view will be pushed. I need that confirm password should be save in sqlite for next time verification.

If I will close my application after validation, then if I will build and run again my application. Now the password validation window should not be open.

Only one view simply will ask the password, if the current password is equal to before terminate application's password, then the application's success view will be open. Now here the validation should be compare with current password with confirm password value[i.e old password, which is stored before terminate my application].

It is possible to do this?
Please  help me

Thanks.

I done this much

```
-(void)insertDatapsw:(NSString *)password:(NSString *)confirmpsw

{

    //[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    sqlite3_stmt *insertStatement = nil;

    NSString *sql;

    int returnvalue;



    sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into LogInPsw(ConfirmPsw) values (?)"];



    returnvalue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &insertStatement, NULL);



    if (returnvalue == SQLITE_DONE)

    {

        NSAssert1 (0,@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }



     //sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1,[strPasswd UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



     sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1,[strConfirmPsw UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



       if (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(insertStatement))

    {

        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



    }

    else

        sqlite3_reset(insertStatement);



    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement);



}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this. Have you tried developing your code further? What did you have a problem with? This isn't a code-on-demand service.

Comment: please provide some code for this problem??? thnak u

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to save the password, once it has been entered correctly, for later usage.

First, I would not use sqlite to save the password. The standard approach would be to use the Keychain. Take a look at this [Keychain example](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html). You can use one of the [many wrappers](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/11/13/keychain-wrappers/) to make life easier.

The easier, but more unsecure way would be to use [NSUserDefaults](http://codeexamples.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/nsuserdefaults-example/), which I would strongly discourage you from.

Having the password and the saved password all you have to do is compare.

Bonus tip: When you save passwords in a database, do NOT save passwords as plain text. Save the hash of the password (you can use something like [SHA2](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm)), then, when the user enters a password, you can compare the passwords hash to the saved one.

Answer (score -1):

You use the 'NSUserDefault`and save password in 'NSUserDefault` and if you close the app and run second time app you see the 'NSUserDefault`value if it exist then go on second view and second condition if you logout the app then you delete the 'NSUserDefault` and next time you run the app then 'NSUserDefault` not exist then you ask for password

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? It seems like you are asking a question to verify what the user wants to do. If so this shouldn't be he as an answer.

Comment: this is answer and am apply this in app and this work perfectly but am not understand your comment . and am only give idea that how you work but am not give the code but  your -ve vote ?

Comment: First of I didn't downvote, I only downvote when there is a real reason for it or need. It just seems like you are asking if this is what he is wanting to do and not saying you need to be doing this. And they are actually asking how to do this code wise not just a description of how he can do it. He probably knows that he should be doing this already, I think providing some code would help and maybe this is the reason why it has a downvote, well this is what I would downvote for if it was me.